# Which tool of Windows form Controlsshould I use to allow the user enter a matrix?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, matrix

I recently finished my Linear and Matrix Algebra class and I wanted to do this little project of doing an advanced matrix calculator. I want it to look nice too in Windows Form. I wanted to make it so that I could ask the size of the matrix first, create a grid of size entered by user to enter the matrix a number in each little square. I just don't know what tool to use. For example, when you play a sudoku game, in some of them it allows u to type in the number in each square. At first I'm going to do it using just integers, but eventually I want to make changes so it can take fractions and decimals too.

Is there any particular tool in which that can be done?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Use a DataGridView, filled with the number of coulmns and then rows you want and set AllowUserto- -Add and -DeleteRows to false.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "DataGridView" control?

I got this:

[image]

It automatically generates rows as the user adds content. There should be a way for you to control it though code and take user input to define the size of the matrix/grid.